# How to easily get most recent version of data for all keys?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I'm trying to create some tables with the following characteristics:

- Stores the all versions of data for a particular key
- Able to easily get the most recent versions of data for all keys

My schema is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE WebSitesStatus(
  -- Host name of the site in question.
  Host String(40) NOT NULL,
  -- When the information on the site was last updated.
  UpdateDate Date NOT NULL,

  HttpsWorks BOOL NOT NULL,
  ModernTls BOOL NOT NULL,

) PRIMARY KEY(Host, UpdateDate DESC);
```

So an example subset of the table might be:

```
+--------------+------------+------------+-----------+
| Host         | UpdateDate | HttpsWorks | ModernTls |
+--------------+------------+------------+-----------+
| foobar.com   | 2016-10-14 | true       | false     |
| google.com   | 2016-10-14 | true       | true      |
| google.com   | 2016-04-23 | false      | false     |
| nytimes.com  | 2016-10-14 | false      | false     |
| nytimes.com  | 2016-05-25 | true       | true      |
| nytimes.com  | 2016-04-25 | true       | false     |
| nytimes.com  | 2016-04-23 | true       | false     |
| paypal.com   | 2016-10-14 | true       | false     | 
+--------------+------------+------------+-----------+
```

I'd like to find a way to get back

```
+--------------+------------+------------+-----------+
| Host         | UpdateDate | HttpsWorks | ModernTls |
+--------------+------------+------------+-----------+
| foobar.com   | 2016-10-14 | true       | false     |
| google.com   | 2016-10-14 | true       | true      |
| nytimes.com  | 2016-10-14 | false      | false     |
| paypal.com   | 2016-10-14 | true       | false     |
+--------------+------------+------------+-----------+
```

but the structure isn't allowing me to easily do this. Is there a way to do this query easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT t.Host, MAX(t.UpdateDate) AS UpdateDate
FROM WebSitesStatus AS t
GROUP BY t.Host
```

returns just the primary keys of the rows you want:

```
+--------------+------------+
| Host         | UpdateDate |
+--------------+------------+
| foobar.com   | 2016-10-14 |
| google.com   | 2016-10-14 |
| nytimes.com  | 2016-10-14 |
| paypal.com   | 2016-10-14 |
+--------------+------------+
```

To get the other columns you must `JOIN` this back to the same table, like this:

```
SELECT p.Host, p.UpdateDate, q.HttpsWorks, q.ModernTls,
FROM (SELECT t.Host, MAX(t.UpdateDate) AS UpdateDate
      FROM WebSitesStatus AS t 
      GROUP BY t.Host) AS p
JOIN WebSitesStatus AS q
ON p.Host = q.Host AND p.UpdateDate = q.UpdateDate;
```

That yields this data, which is what you wanted:

```
+--------------+------------+------------+-----------+
| Host         | UpdateDate | HttpsWorks | ModernTls 
+--------------+------------+------------+-----------+
| amazon.co.uk | 2016-10-14 | true       | false     |
| amazon.com   | 2016-10-14 | true       | true      |
| nytimes.com  | 2016-10-14 | false      | false     |
| paypal.com   | 2016-10-14 | true       | false     |
+--------------+------------+------------+-----------+
```

This is somewhat inefficient, because it scans your table twice: once to get the primary key values and then again to fetch all the other values. But it's probably the cleanest approach.